# MySQL Query works fast as SELECT, hangs on INSERT... SELECT or CREATE TABLE... SELECT

Tags: mysql

Got a real head scratcher here. Here are my two test tables to illustrate:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `atest` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `testval` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `testval` (`testval`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `atestb` (
  `id` bigint(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lookup` bigint(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `lookup` (`lookup`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The tables have too many records to paste the data values in here, but you can download tables with data here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2301830/lookuptest.sql

My problem: I must find the **first** record in atestb.lookup that is greater than or equal to the value in atest.testval for each record in atest.

After trying several different methods, it turns out the fastest way to get this result is this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.testval, 
 (SELECT lookup 
     FROM atestb
     WHERE lookup >= a.testval
     ORDER BY lookup LIMIT 1)
  AS closest
 FROM atest a
```

So that works great and fast. However the problem is I then need to use this query to create a new table. It's a temporary table in this case, but I've tried it with a permanent table and get the same results. If I run:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptbl
   SELECT a.id, a.testval, 
    (SELECT lookup 
     FROM atestb
     WHERE lookup >= a.testval
     ORDER BY lookup LIMIT 1)
     AS closest
FROM atest a
```

It just hangs indefinitely on "Sending data..." and I have to kill the process. I've also tried creating the table and then using INSERT INTO TABLE tmptbl, and I get the same result.

The problem is clearly with the subquery-derived column, because if I leave that out or substitute a different value, it works. It also works if atest only has a few records in it, but the actual table has 45K records.

If there's another way to do the query without the subquery, that's fine too, but something like this:

```
 SELECT a . * , MIN( b.lookup )
    FROM `atest` a
    LEFT JOIN atestb b ON b.lookup >= a.testval
    GROUP BY a.id
```

... is also crazily inefficient because of the join being on >=. So it hangs as well. My subquery works well...but it just won't insert into a table.

Results of EXPLAIN (it's the same whether for a plain SELECT or INSERT...SELECT):

```
id | select_type        |table   |type   | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
       -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | PRIMARY            | a      | ALL   | NULL          | NULL   | NULL    | NULL |45886 | NULL
 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | atestb | index | lookup        | lookup | 8       | NULL |    1 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2); Using index`
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Can you show a result of a Explain of your query 45k rows is nothing big at all.

Comment: you probably need to read this http://www.mysqlab.net/knowledge/kb/detail/topic/performance/id/5114

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, it's nothing at all and as I say it works fine for a plain SELECT. We do much more complex queries on much larger tables all the time. The issue only happens when trying to insert into or create a table from the statement. I've added the output from EXPLAIN - it is the same whether a plain SELECT or an INSERT... SELECT: